# fork() and virtual address spaces

Tags: c, memory, fork

Here is what I have understood so far - virtual and physical address space are divided in pages with the same size, lets say 100 bytes(just for the example) so the addresses in a page that one can address are from 0 to 99 and when a given virtual page is needed, it is mapped to physical memory. So when using `fork()` you get a separate process with its own address space and copy of all variables from the parent process which are now in the child's address space. My first question is - does every page starts from address 0, because if I define a variable in the parent's address space and print it from both processes, it gives me the same address? Second question is - the program memory consists of Text,Data,Heap,Stack, is this all one page in memory?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think it's important to discern between virtual page (or just page) and a page frame (in physical memory). Therefore, a page frame is what is *really* in physical RAM, and it can be mapped to one or more virtual address of one or more processes.

> the addresses in a page that one can address are from 0 to 99 and when a given virtual page is needed, it is mapped to physical memory

This assertion sounds strange to me. I am not sure what you mean exactly here.

> So when using `fork()` you get a separate process with its own address space and copy of all variables from the parent process which are now in the child's address space.

Yes and no. What `fork()` does is to clone the virtual address space of the parent into the child process. After that, the virtual addresses will be the same in both processes but not everything is *copied*. There are the same page frames in physical memory, but now they are mapped to an additional process (the child) using Copy on Write. Once the child attempts to write to any page, it will trigger a `pagefault` and the OS will allocate a page frame.

> does every page starts from address 0, because if I define a variable in the parent's address space and print it from both processes, it gives me the same address?

No, it just shares the same virtual address than the parent. If ASLR is enabled, that address is randomized (was decided at the parent's `exec()`) and it will be different if you try several executions.

> the program memory consists of Text,Data,Heap,Stack, is this all one page in memory?

No, think again what a page is. If we are assuming that our system has pages of 100 bytes, if text is 1 KiB we will have 11 pages for that...
In addition, not all the regions you name are mapped together, but it depends on different systems. For example, Linux with ASLR maps the text, data and heap regions together, while the stack and libraries are separated. You can check an example in `/proc/self/maps`

Comment: I believe ASLR happens when a program is loaded into an address space by `exec()`, not when a process is forked.

Comment: Yes that's correct, I didn't say the opposite. In my example, ASLR was applied to the parent process, and the virtual address space is shared with the child. Thanks I edited the answer just to clarify this point.